# Efficiently read arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 4-dimensional array L. `L.shape = [31, 13, 250, 501]`

I need to perform operations which use different elements.

Method 1:

```
for i1 in range(31):
    for i2 in range(15):
        for i3 in range(250):
            for i4 in range(501):
                L[i1, i2, i3, i4] # some operations involving this element
```

Method 2:

```
for i2 in range(15):
    for i1 in range(31):
        for i4 in range(501):
            for i3 in range(250):
                L[i1, i2, i3, i4] # some operations involving this element
```

Does the speed of execution dependent on how for loops are nested?

Comment: [`timeit.timeit`?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: Probably not. But please consider using NumPy which allows you to build a 4D array and to manipulate it at once without loops. And that's MUCH faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the pattern

```
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        #do stuff
```

involves calling the `range()` function `a+1` times. If `a > b`, this will be less efficient than

```
for j in range(b):
    for i in range(a):
        #do stuff
```

You can work out that

```
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        for k in range(c):
            for l in range(d):
                #do stuff
```

calls the range function `1 + a + a*b + a*b*c` many times, which is minimized when `a <= b <= c <= d`. In your case, you can work out that the difference between the most efficient and least efficient ways of looping (measured by number of range calls) is a factor of roughly 34, which is more than I had initially expected. This doesn't mean that one approach will be 34 times quicker than the other. In typical code, the body of the inmost loop dominates the execution time no matter how you manage the bookkeeping.

Having said all this, switching to [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) (if you are not already using it) is probably the best approach for making the code run fast.

Comment: Hadn't thought of the number of times the range is executed! After a bit of googling, I realize that I hadn't phrased my question well. I wanted to ask if there is a natural ascending storage order for arrays in python (like fortran, where column-major order is followed)?

Comment: @gksamarth With plain Python lists (which are themselves always 1 dimensional) you follow pointers to the actual data, so the question in some ways doesn't even make sense. In NumPy, it does make sense. Look at the entry for row major in the [Numpy Glossary](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html) to get confirmation that NumPy uses row major. But -- if you are using NumPy then there is usually a better way that using indices tied to `range()` to iterate over the elements.